# Set a variable within switch statement Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch statement to check whether an object is instance of a specific type, if it is I would like to set a string variable and then return it at the end at the method.

Whenever I run my tests 'detailMessage' always comes back as null, am I doing the switch case incorrectly?

```
 private String returnDetailMessage(Discount discountType, Object quantity, Object claims) {
            String detailMessage
            switch (objectType) {
                case objectType instanceof Percentage:
                    if (quantity > claims) {
                        detailMessage = "There are not enough discounted strings for you to do this"
                        break
                    } else {
                        detailMessage = "this is a discount string."
                        break
                    }
                case objectType instanceof FixedAmount:
                    if (quantity > claims) {
                        detailMessage = "There are not enough discounted Strings to cover the amount of quantity you have"
                        break
                    } else {
                        detailMessage = "there is a fixed amount here where quantity is less than claims"
                        break
                    }
            }
          return detailMessage
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use instanceof, just specify the class.

Also when pulling fields from the discountType we use just that rather than a specific percentage/fixedAmount type?

```
private String returnDetailMessage(Discount discountType, Object quantity, Object claims) {
            String detailMessage
            switch (discountType) {
                case Percentage:
                    if (quantity > claims) {
                        detailMessage = "There are not enough discounted strings for you to do this"
                        break
                    } else {
                        detailMessage = "this is a discount string."
                        break
                    }
                case FixedAmount:
                    if (quantity > claims) {
                        detailMessage = "There are not enough discounted Strings to cover the amount of quantity you have"
                        break
                    } else {
                        detailMessage = "there is a fixed amount here where quantity is less than claims"
                        break
                    }
            }
          return detailMessage
        }
```